# Equivalent of CONVERT in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, string, date, ssis

I've got three columns as follows:

```
Date Manufactured    Date Shipped    Date Arrived
    25.12.2013        01.05.2014      01.12.2014
```

I'd like to turn them into a datetime in SQL.  How would I do the equivalent of

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '23.10.2016', 104)
```

in SSIS?

Comment: Check out `Derived Column Task` [Sample Link](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/211/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-data-flow/). Another option is `Script Component Task`

Answer (score 1):

If your source component is a SQL table, the best way to do it is to use a query that includes the CONVERT() function instead of a straight pull from the table.

Otherwise, your next best option is the Derived Column component as t_m mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can try derived column code:

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(SUBSTRING(datestr,FINDSTRING(datestr,".",2) + 1,4) + "-" + 
 SUBSTRING(datestr,FINDSTRING(datestr,".",1) + 1,FINDSTRING(datestr,".",2) - 
                                                 FINDSTRING(datestr,".",1) - 1) + "-" +
 SUBSTRING(datestr,1,FINDSTRING(datestr,".",1) - 1))
```